# How does WD-40 remove rust?

Tags: physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, solvents

One of the often-touted uses of WD-40 is that it "[dissolves rust](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/6229/57278)". The official website states that WD-40 "[breaks down the bonds between metal and rust](http://www.wd40.com.au/faqs/can-wd-40-remove-rust/)".

I can't understand how this would work, since [there seem to be no rust-dissolving ingredients](https://www.wired.com/2009/04/st-whatsinside-6/) in WD-40 and it seems the product is more basic than acidic.

A (possibly not exhaustive) list of ingredients:

- [Mineral oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral_oil), I guess for lubrication and rust protection layer (but not a rust solvent?)
- [Decane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decane), freeze-resisting
- [Nonane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonane), water-displacing
- [Tetradecane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetradecane), freeze-resisting and water-repelling
- [Undecane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecane), freeze-resisting and water-repelling
- [Dimethyl Naphthalene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,6-Dimethylnaphthalene) (C<sub>12</sub>H<sub>12</sub>), likely used as a solvent
- [Cyclohexane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclohexane), solvent
- [Carbon dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide), likely used as a propellant

I can imagine that the low viscosity of WD-40 allows it to get in all nooks, making it easier to grind rust particles away because it acts as a short-term lubricant. Is that actually how it works, or am I missing something?

Comment: Related: [How does WD40 displace water?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/50741/7951)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say it works by coming out as a liquid. Then it diffuses through the porous rust layer or travels along the steel edge and expands to gas- as the mixture has a highly suppressed vaporisation point to push the rust from the inside. Steel has a high surface affinity for hydrocarbons as demonstrated by high difficult it is to clean. Partial vaporisation is plenty powerful enough to knock off rust.